# How to bind a datagrid column combobox to a second-level list

Tags: c#, wpf, list, datagrid, combobox

hear is the problem, I Have a class, namely "Owner", which has a list of another class named "Animal". Now I want to show the owners in a grid with a combo column that reflect their animals.

Below is the code (I made it as simple as possible):

XAML Code for datagrid:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgvTest" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding OwnerId}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding OwnerName}"/>
  <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Animals" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The Owner Class:

```
public class Owner
{
    private int ownerId;

    public int OwnerId
    {
        get { return ownerId; }
        set { ownerId = value; }
    }

    private string ownerName;

    public string OwnerName
    {
        get { return ownerName; }
        set { ownerName = value; }
    }

    private List<Animal> animals;

    public List<Animal> Animals
    {
        get { return animals; }
        set { animals = value; }
    }

}
```

The Animal Class:

```
public class Animal
{
    private int animalId;

    public int AnimalId
    {
        get { return animalId; }
        set { animalId = value; }
    }

    private string animalName;

    public string AnimalName
    {
        get { return animalName; }
        set { animalName = value; }
    }
}
```

And the Load event is as follows:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Owner> owners = new List<Owner>();
        Animal a1 = new Animal();
        a1.AnimalId = 1;
        a1.AnimalName = "Dog";

        Animal a2 = new Animal();
        a2.AnimalId = 2;
        a2.AnimalName = "Cat";

        Owner o1 = new Owner();
        o1.Animals = new List<Animal>();
        o1.Animals.Add(a1);
        o1.Animals.Add(a2);

        o1.OwnerId = 1;
        o1.OwnerName = "John";



        Animal a3 = new Animal();
        a3.AnimalId = 3;
        a3.AnimalName = "Mouse";

        Animal a4 = new Animal();
        a4.AnimalId = 4;
        a4.AnimalName = "Sheep";

        Owner o2 = new Owner();
        o2.Animals = new List<Animal>();
        o2.Animals.Add(a3);
        o2.Animals.Add(a4);

        o2.OwnerId = 2;
        o2.OwnerName = "Jennifer";

        owners.Add(o1);
        owners.Add(o2);

        dgvTest.DataContext = owners;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set **`ItemsSource`** value on **`EditingElementStyle`** and **`ElementStyle`**. Also in case you want to show `AnimalName` in comboBox, set **`DisplayMemberPath`** to Animal

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Animals}"/>
            <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="AnimalName"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Animals}"/>
            <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="AnimalName"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

---

**UPDATE**

In case you want to retain selection of comboBox, you need to have one **`SelectedAnimal`** property in class **`Owner`** and bind **`SelectedItem`** property of comboBox to that property.

In *Owner* class:

```
private Animal selectedAnimal;
public Animal SelectedAnimal
{
   get { return selectedAnimal; }
   set { selectedAnimal = value; }
}
```

*XAML*

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Animals}"/>
            <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="AnimalName"/>
            <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding SelectedAnimal}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Animals}"/>
            <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="AnimalName"/>
            <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding SelectedAnimal}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: Thank you, It will populate now but won't stay when I leave the cell!

Comment: For that you have to bind to some property in Owner class. See the update in answer.

Comment: Thanks, it is working now :)
but my reputation won't allow me to vote you up :(